# Bot notification - App title cut off on IOS

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

When our bot sends a notification to a channel the app name on the notification gets cut off on IOS devices. The title on desktop, web and Andriod devices is 'Peer to Peer' but on IOS devices it gets cut off at 'Peer to.' There is no difference in code between devices.

[IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yNL1.png)

[Andriod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8jKr.jpg)

Comment: We are able to repro your issue. We have raised a bug for the same. We will let you know once we have any updates on it.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Do you have a link to the issue?

Comment: This bug has been fixed now. We have tested this on IOS Teams version 5.12.0 and IOS version 16.5.1

Could you please test it and confirm once?

Comment: We are having this issue as well I think. It does not show the name of the app but instead just shows the bot name (from Azure). This only happens on iOS. It works fine on Android and Desktop (Windows)

Comment: @Niels Brinch
Based on the information provided, it seems that you are experiencing an issue where the app icon is not displayed on iOS devices and instead, the bot name is shown. This is a known behavior in Teams on iOS devices. On iOS, the app icon is not displayed for anonymous users and instead, the bot name is shown as the sender of the message or card. There is no direct solution to change this behavior on iOS devices. It is a limitation of the Teams platform on iOS.

Comment: Is the user considered anonymous? The user is logged into the Teams app.

Comment: @NielsBrinch - We have tested this on IOS 16.6.1 and Teams version 5.17.1. At our end we are getting App name on notification not the bot's name.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR0zK.png
Could you please update the IOS and Teams version and check again?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT It seems to work when we recently logged in to Teams. But most users do not log into Teams regularly. They keep their session alive for months and then it stops working. I think that is what is happening, but we cannot be sure. (and yes, we confirmed that we have the newest version of both iOS and Teams and that we can still reproduce the issue)

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed.
We have tested this on IOS Teams version 5.12.0 and IOS version 16.5.1

Comment: We continue to see this behaviour. It works fine, then I go on one week vacation, and when I come back, it fails again. My versions are fully updated. We are seeing it frequently across several hundred thousand users.

Comment: We have tested again at our end, but it was working fine. Could you please share the detailed repro steps to test at our end?